# Unity. Анимация группы (изображение+текст)

Tags: unity3d, анимация, 2d

Необходимо произвести анимацию группы элементов, а именно (изображение + текст) на некоторое расстояние вверх и исчезновение. Проблема в том что текст находится на слое GUI.
Наглядно что требуется. Пишу кликер и по клику миши должна показываться иконка валюты + текст, сколько далось и это все двигаться. UPD: необходимо реализовать floating text

Comment: Для получения ответа поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример кода

Answer (score 1):

"на слое GUI" если имелось ввиду, что ты используешь GUI, то мой тебе совет переходи на UI будет в разы проще.
При использовании UI вкладываете (делаете дочерним) в image (иконка валюты) text и достаточно анимировать только image, а text как дочерний будет иметь тот же самый эффект

Comment: Не совсем силен в понятиях unity еще, только начал. Да я использую UI. Я так пробовал, у меня получилась "одноразовая" анимация, то есть если image так и оставить на scene, анимация проиграется и все хорошо. Но в дальнейшем мне надо по клику создавать этот префаб и двигать его. Что увы у меня не получается

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался с этим. Получилось так:

На сцене создается пустой `gameobject`. Далее добавляем `Canvas` → `Image` → `Text`. Создается Prefab. (для удобства лучше изменить `scale` canvas'а. В моем случае подошло значение 0.005). В скрипте где отслеживаются клики мышкой создаем объект по координатам мыши и уничтожаем спустя 2 секунды (время любое).

Comment: А что же постеснялись код анимации выложить? Это было бы кстати)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский , советую почитать мой ответ и получишь еще более красивый результат

Comment: @Kiya мне лично пофиг

Answer (score 0):

1. Использование GUI плохая идея т.к. это плохая и устаревшая технология. Она очень медленная и неудобная в работе(удобно для тестов вроде отображения FPS). Используй NGUI (канвас + UI обьекты)
2. Для анимаций подобного рода советую использовать бесплатный ассет LeanTween. Он очень удобный в использовании + имеет разные варианты функций для анимаций (ищи по Ease если хочешь красивую анимацию).Она простая в использовании и очень быстрая.